# Automatic Sequential Numbering

Tags: list, workflow

Creating an automatic sequential numbering.  I want to reset the number back to 1 to start again at 1 for the next set of unique ids.

Example:

```
0001-01 0001-02 0001-03

0002-01 0002-02 0002-03 0002-04
```

I thought I could do this in a workflow with setting variable to 1 then add to it for each of the same numbers, then reset it back to 1 for the next set of number.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 Online

Comment: Check out using designer workflow loops to iterate through the list items. You should be able to calculate variables to number sequentially, as long as there's a rule you can set for when to start the numbers back over.